# How can i save and restore android WebView's WebBackForwardList?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to implement a simple web browser app using WebView with android studio. I want to save my WebView's state (e.g. WebBackForwardList) to internal storage and restore it when i relaunch the app. I don't want to just load last visited url, instead i also want that when i call `goBack()` or `goForward()` methods of my WebView i want it to restore previous and next visited links from internal storage.

I've currently implemented my own WebView, WebViewClient and WebChromeClient and saving visited links as strings to internal storage so i can load them by calling `loadUrl()` in override methods of `goBack()` and `goForward()` while restoring. But this makes pages to load slower than WebView's own `goBack()` and `goForward()` methods and also it doesn't restore scroll position, zoom etc.

So i have two questions;

there is a way to get WebBackForwardList of WebView by calling `copyBackForwardList()` method, but is there a way to set/edit WebBackForwardList?

If not, how can i save and restore it after restart the app?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best solution, but i implemented a workaround for this situation. In simple words, I'm saving WebBackForwardList's items' URL's from zero to current index to a `Stack` named `backStack`, from current index plus one to last index to `forwardStack`. Then I save these stacks and current item's URL to internal storage.

When the app is restarted, WebView loads the current item URL. When the user wants to go back or forward, I first check wether WebView can go back or forward. If it can, I call `goBack()` method of WebView. If it can't, then I pop from the stacks I saved to internal storage and load the URL.

But when loading URL from `backStack`, I had to push current WebBackForwardList's items' URL's to `forwardStack` and clear WebView history. This is necessary because WebView saves last loaded URL to last index of WebBackForwardList. And this distorts WebBackForwardList because I am loading a previous item.

It's currently working fine, but as I said this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `restoreState` and `saveState` to implement saving & restoring.

```
class AppWebTab extents WebView{
    long unique_tab_id;
   
    public void boolean load(){
        File stackpath = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "webstack"+unique_tab_id);

        if(stackpath.exists()) {
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            byte[] data = ...//read file as Byte Array
            parcel.unmarshall(data, 0, data.length); 
            parcel.setDataPosition(0);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.readFromParcel(parcel);
            parcel.recycle();
            
            WebBackForwardList stacks = restoreState(bundle);
            
            if(stacks!=null && stacks.getSize()>0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    public void save(){
        File stackpath = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "webstack"+unique_tab_id);
        
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        
        WebBackForwardList stacks = saveState(bundle);

        if(stacks!=null&&stacks.getSize()>0) {
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.setDataPosition(0);
            bundle.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
            byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
            parcel.recycle();
           ...//save Byte Array Data to file
        } else {
            stackpath.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to the effort put into chromium, the saved BackForwardList is even navigable when the device is offline but the local cache is available.

But you cannot modified WebBackForwardList directly. So if you have multiple webviews representing one single browser tab (luxury but sometimes useful), It's hard to merge and save multiple BackForwardList as one, which is a pity.

---

Like  @j__m said, system upgrade and format change may cause this method to fail. After testing, the data of WebView (`WEBVIEW_CHROMIUM_STATE`) has a certain downward compatibility, while the Parcelable does not.

In the test, the data stored using Parcel cannot cross the Android version. For this reason, I must use `ObjectOutputStream` to implement my own serialization method, which is almost the same. As a result, the data saved with ObjectOutputStream survived the update from Android 4.4 to Android 9, and can be parsed to restore the pages successfully.

[code](https://github.com/KnIfER/PolymPic/blob/master/ActivityLauncher/src/main/java/com/knziha/polymer/webstorage/WebStacksSer.java)

---

Data format compatibility must be considered, especially when syncing tabs across various versions of android devices.

Now using this technology + webdav server and with the same version of webview.apk installed, I enable the user to share browsing states from android 9 -> android 6, and vice versa !

If the versions of webview.apk differ, or if it's not installed at all, then you will have forward-compatibility issues and the web page will apear blank (no crashing observed). but the  backward-compatibility is still ok.

---

2021 Update : observed crash after downgrading webview.apk from version 92.* dev to version 91.* . It says `render process crashed`, so you need to implement `onRenderProcessGone` and return true in your custom `WebViewClient`.

Comment: This way is very reasonable, properly storing the state of the webview (even scroll position). However, the app will crash if the bundle size exceeds 2048kb. Hope there is a way to optimize the bundle data to work properly (I think state of webview stored into bundle have much much stuffs that we no need to store).

Comment: You won't reach that number. The history stack will trim itself to around 200kb.

Comment: The `Parcelable` format is only supposed to be used for IPC, not persistent storage. Any Android update can introduce an incompatible change and, at best, lose your history, at worst, cause your app to throw an exception and thus crash if you're not prepared to catch it.

Instead, you're supposed to loop over the Bundle's keys and store each value yourself. It's more code than using `Parcel` but it has the advantage of actually working.

Comment: So the data format of Parcelable and webview may change, causing this method to fail. I wonder if the possibility of this failure is high? And will the failure crash my app?