# save webview state in fragment

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm basically using navigation component with graph.  I navigate from home fragment to web fragment when I open the url in a webview.  My issue is that I want to save the webview state when I leave web fragment, and when I come back, I want to show the saved instance instead of reloading the whole page, but what I have done so far is not working.  If anyone could help , I would appreciate it. Thank you

- This is my code

```
 public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
        webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        if(webViewBundle != null){
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        } else {
            assert getArguments() != null;
            String url = getArguments().getString("url");
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `onSaveInstanceState` method instead of creating "dummy" `Bundle`, saving `WebView`s state into it (in `onPause`) and then... doing nothing with this `Bundle` - it will be gc'ed and state is lost (when `Fragment` gets destroyed and new instance will be created)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it is not really working as well ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the created bundle somewhere. Depending on the use case the place you store it may be different – the use case `saveState` is designed for is during activity recreation you put it in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState`, as suggested in @snachmsm's answer.

But this won't help if you want to handle the case where the user navigates away and the fragment is removed from the back stack. For example, if you have a tabbed activity with multiple fragments. In that case, you may want to pass the bundle up to the activity to hold onto, and use the patterns described in https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate.

For example, you can define the view model like this:

```
class WebViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val webViewState = Bundle()
}
```

And then share them between the activity and the fragment:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: WebViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}

class WebFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: WebViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(): View {
        val webview = ... // inflate the webview
        webview.restoreState(viewModel.webViewState)
        return webview
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        webView.saveState(viewModel.webViewState)
    }
}
```

---

If you want to go further than that, to get the user back onto the same page even if the Activity finishes, as far as I can find there is no good way to do that. Since `Bundle` itself is not persistable, you cannot write it to disk without risking compatibility issues. It may work depending on the WebView implementation, as described in [How can i save and restore android WebView's WebBackForwardList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469477/how-can-i-save-and-restore-android-webviews-webbackforwardlist), but be prepared to handle any errors if you try to do that.

There is also `copyBackForwardList()`, which allows you to get the `WebBackForwardList`, and all its public API data is persistable. However, there is no API to restore / set / inject that list back into WebView after recreation, so you'll have to resort to replaying the history by repeatedly calling `setUrl`, or use the [javascript History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

None of these are particularly good options, so I would suggest looking into whether the "restore" requirements can be relaxed to only go back to the last (current) page on the stack rather than restoring the full history. Obviously not ideal, but it's a reasonable compromise if you are just embedding a webview for interactions with a few simple web pages rather than building your own browser.

Comment: is there anyway to simply push back that fragment into backstack without killing it and the next i call it from backstack ? or it will also destroyed in this case ?

Comment: If that fragment is outside of the backstack, something has to hold onto a reference to it. If the activity hasn't been destroyed, you can use that. But if the user navigated away, then no, your app's whole process can be killed by the framework at that point

Comment: Yeah i don't like the activity is destroy , while activity is up , i navigation back to the same fragment with backstack or something ( sound more like hide and how fragment  , instead of reloading the content of it everytime ) , any way to do that thank you

Comment: Yes, in that case you would use `saveState` to get the bundle, pass it to a `ViewModel` shared with the activity as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#viewmodel). Then when you create the new fragment, you pass reuse that same `ViewModel` instead of creating a new one

Comment: Thank you for your help , could you please show some code and it works i'll mark it as correct

Comment: Added that above. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for adding some code , i have done as you said but state is not saved , this is how it looks like in my code , am i doing anything wrong https://ibb.co/BKmRGCv